# Comparing new data of drugsfda

Tags: openfda, drugs

How can I effectively compare this extensive dataset with the previous version I downloaded, especially considering that I need to re-download the updated dataset each time it's refreshed?

Furthermore, every record doesn't have pdfs linked to them

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of technologies out there that can assist in comparing what has changed in the dataset compared to previous versions you loaded. We don't release specific update logs, but programmatically comparing to previous versions saved in a database should prove effective in revealing what has changed. Not every record has a pdf linked in the upstream data source, so unfortunately that persists in our translation of this data.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead